# Unexcepted issue in Rails 4.2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing an unexpected issue in Rails project, i just installed a fresh project and when I tried to run the command "rails -v" it shows me the following error:

```
/home/ourdesignz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/bin/rails:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
```

I am using the following versions of Ruby on Rails.

```
Ruby Version: 2.3.4  
Rals Version: 4.2.7.1
```

It also doesn't allow me to run any migrations, in that case when I try to run "rake db:migrate" then it gives me the following error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- rake (LoadError)
```

Comment: Did you do `bundle install` from rails app directory?? If not, run it. Then run mentioned commands.

Comment: By the way, if this is a brand new project then is there a good reason why you are using rails version `4.2`? You'd be better off using the current latest version, i.e. `5.1`.

Comment: i used it because it was needed, i have to use older version, that's why

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

or

```
bin/rake db:migrate
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about rails -v?

Comment: `bundle exec rails -v` or, if you are using binstubs, `bin/rails -v`.

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails -v`. I think your `bin/bash path` not include `ruby gem bin path`, what is your ruby version manager? rbenv or rvm? Make sure you already ran `bundle install` to install required gems.

Comment: i have already installed bundle install, and the commands you specified are not working

Comment: Can you post output of `which rake` or `which rails` command?